# Why is S3 CLI returning no CommonPrefixes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to list the 'folders' in a S3 bucket under a given prefix.

```
aws --profile my-profile s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket my-bucket --prefix releases/com/example/app/ --delimiter / --query 'CommonPrefixes[*].Prefix'
```

There are dozens of folders under the prefix, each containing many files, I I should be able to list the folders., i.e. they do exist

There is no `CommonPrefixes` returned by this query, so I get `null` as an output.  What am I doing wrong?

- running `aws-cli/2.0.0 Python/3.7.5 Windows/10 botocore/2.0.0dev4` in Git Bash terminal on Windows.

Comment: Working okay for me using that syntax. Are you positive that `my-profile` has sufficient IAM permissions to list the objects under that bucket/prefix?

Comment: I've just found that it appears that the CLI works differently when running on Bash for Windows than in CMD. When run in CMD using that syntax it works too.

Comment: It might be due to the delimiter — try putting the parameters in quotes (eg `--delimiter "/"`) because I know that CommonPrefixes only appear if a delimiter is specified.